# How to printf a array without describing the format of each element?

Tags: arrays, perl, printf

I want to print several arrays and the element of output will with field width 3 , I think I can use `printf` , but if I use `printf` then I need to write the format of all element of array , but the array is big .

for example

```
@array = (1,10,100,30);
printf ("%3d %3d %3d %3d\n",$array[0],$array[1],$array[2],$array[3]);
```

I know I can use loop to print a element until all the array loop through , but I think it's not a good idea .

Does there exists any way can let me just describe the format of element one time , then apply to the whole array automatically?

something like this?

```
printf ("%3d\n",@array);
```

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

1. Use a loop

   ```
   printf "%3d ", $_  for @array;
   print "\n";
   ```
2. Use the `x` operator to build a variable length template

   ```
   printf "%3d " x @array . "\n", @array;
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Try this concoction:

```perl
print( map( {sprintf("%3d\n", $_)} @array));
```

Comment: \* `print join(" ", map { sprintf "%3d", $_ } @array), "\n"`