# Smart formatting of print output

Tags: perl

Hi,

as a new user to StackExchange I would like to boldly start contributing with
asking Perl question.

In a script for dealing 52 standard deck cards between 4 players [1]
the part of printing the cards needs some correction.

Now I have W and E sides printed in separate rows:

```
♠ J 9 7 6                                                                       
♥ K                                                                             
♦ K J 9 3 2                                                                     
♣ A 3 2                                                                         
                                                ♠ A K 5 3                       
                                                ♥ Q                             
                                                ♦ 8 7 6 5                       
                                                ♣ 9 6 5 4
```

but those should be in the same rows:

```
♠ J 9 7 6                                       ♠ A K 5 3                       
♥ K                                             ♥ Q                             
♦ K J 9 3 2                                     ♦ 8 7 6 5                       
♣ A 3 2                                         ♣ 9 6 5 4
```

so each color (suit) symbol of E side is printed in the same row of
corresponding suit symbol of W side and in the same given column as
the remaining suit symbols of E side.

W and E corresponding suits were printed using print:

```
# last suit (clubs: A 3 2) of W side                                            
print "\x{2663} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @wc); print "\n";
# first suit (spades: A K 5 3) of E side                                        
print "\t\t\t\t\t\t\x{2660} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @es); print "\n";
```

Taking into account that W side suit length may vary due to shuffling, it seems
to me that tabs should be avoided or swapped for something else for printing E side.
How to print E side then?

[1] [Script source](https://github.com/matthiam1/SPADES/blob/master/q.pl)

Comment: Well, you'll have to rearrange your prints (and so perhaps reorganize code) --- after the first `J 9 7 6` don't print newline but leave some space and then print `A K 5 3`, then the newline.  Etc. Note that `sprintf` is your friend for this. (And then there are modules for tabular layout of prints.)

Comment: See also [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form)

Comment: @zdim: thanks for suggestion. The script now prints correctly. I used:  
- printf to print array elements got from `for` loop as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457175/how-to-printf-a-array-without-describing-the-format-of-each-element#answer-18457309)  
- and printf feature `%*s` that enables dynamic setting of field width depending
on a length of all array elements combined as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457175/how-to-printf-a-array-without-describing-the-format-of-each-element#answer-18457309).

Comment: Good to hear that :)   The `sprintf` is good to be aware of (for format/representation conversions as well).  And then you got that great answer from Dave :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach is to just interleave the lines of code that print the East and West hands (and remove the newlines from the first `print()` lines in each pair).

```
print "\x{2660} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @ws);
print "\t\t\t\t\x{2660} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @es); print "\n";
print "\x{2665} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @wh);
print "\t\t\t\t\x{2665} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @eh); print "\n";
print "\x{2666} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @wd);
print "\t\t\t\t\x{2666} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @ed); print "\n";
print "\x{2663} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @wc);
print "\t\t\t\t\x{2663} "; print $deck{$_}," " foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} @ec); print "\n";
```

The first time I ran that, I got this result which nicely illustrates the problem:

```
♠ 9 3 2                 ♠ A K Q J 7 6 
♥ 9 6 5 4               ♥ Q 7 
♦ 10 8              ♦ A 3 
♣ 9 8 3 2               ♣ K 10 5
```

Because West only has two hearts, East's hearts are printed too far to the left. We can fix this, but it will be good to simplify your code a bit first. Let's write a subroutine called `suit_hand()` that takes one of your arrays of cards and returns the string we need to print.

```
sub suit_hand {
  my $symbol = shift;
  my @positions = sort { $a <=> $b} @_;
  my @cards = map { $deck{$_} } @positions;
  return "$symbol " . join ' ', @cards;
}
```

We can then remove a lot of repetitive code from your program.

```
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ns), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @nh), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @nd), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @nc), "\n";
print suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ws), "\t\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @es), "\n";
print suit_hand("\x{2665}", @wh), "\t\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @eh), "\n";
print suit_hand("\x{2666}", @wd), "\t\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @ed), "\n";
print suit_hand("\x{2663}", @wc), "\t\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @ec), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ss), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @sh), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @sd), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @sc), "\n";
```

Nothing has changed in the output yet, we've just made the code a bit easier to work with.

So the middle four lines are the ones that print the East and West hands. And that's where our current problem is. To be precise, it's the string of tabs in the middle of those lines that are causing the problems. We would like to get rid of those and replace them with a better way of formatting the output.

And that's what [`printf()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) gives us. It's a "formatted `print()`" function. We can call it like this:

```
printf "%-40s %s\n", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ws), suit_hand("\x{2660}", @es);
```

The first argument (`"%-40s %s\n"`) is the format string. The `%s` means "insert a string here" and the `-40` in the first string position means "format this string as left-justified and 40 characters long" - meaning that our second string will always start in the 41st position.

Following the format string, the second and third arguments are just the strings we want inserted into our output. In this case, that's just the strings returned from our two calls to `suit_hand()`.

So our code becomes this:

```
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ns), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @nh), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @nd), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @nc), "\n";
printf "%-40s %s\n", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ws), suit_hand("\x{2660}", @es);
printf "%-40s %s\n", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @wh), suit_hand("\x{2665}", @eh);
printf "%-40s %s\n", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @wd), suit_hand("\x{2666}", @ed);
printf "%-40s %s\n", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @wc), suit_hand("\x{2663}", @ec);
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2660}", @ss), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2665}", @sh), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2666}", @sd), "\n";
print "\t\t\t", suit_hand("\x{2663}", @sc), "\n";
```

And here's some example output:

```
                    ♠ 8 5
                    ♥ 5
                    ♦ K Q 9 7 5
                    ♣ Q 8 4 3 2
♠ K Q 10 9                               ♠ A 4
♥ 10 9 8 3                               ♥ Q 4 2
♦ A J 8 4                                ♦ 6 3 2
♣ A                                      ♣ K 10 9 7 6
                    ♠ J 7 6 3 2
                    ♥ A K J 7 6
                    ♦ 10
                    ♣ J 5
```

Note that it does the right thing, even though West only has a single spade in his hand.

Obviously, you can change the number 40 in the `printf()` call to whatever value looks best to you.

**Update:** Because I was a bit bored over lunch, I wrote a version of your program which shows how I would have approached the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my @suits = qw[spades hearts diamonds clubs];

my %suit = (
  spades   => "\x{2660}",
  hearts   => "\x{2665}",
  diamonds => "\x{2666}",
  clubs    => "\x{2663}",
);

my @deck;
for my $s (keys %suit) {
  for my $c (2 .. 14) {
    push @deck, [$s, $c];
  }
}

@deck = shuffle @deck;

my %hand;

for (1 .. 13) {
  for my $p (qw[s w n e]) {
    my $card = shift @deck;

    push @{ $hand{$p}{$card->[0]} }, $card->[1];
  }
}

show1hand($hand{n});
show2hands($hand{w}, $hand{e});
show1hand($hand{s});

sub show1hand {
  my $hand = shift;

  for (@suits) {
    print "\t\t\t", suit_hand($_, $hand->{$_}), "\n";
  }
}

sub show2hands {
  my ($hand1, $hand2) = @_;

  for (@suits) {
    printf "%-40s %s\n",
      suit_hand($_, $hand1->{$_}),
      suit_hand($_, $hand2->{$_});
  }
}

sub suit_hand {
  my ($suit, $cards) = @_;

  my %display = (11 => 'J', 12 => 'Q', 13 => 'K', 14 => 'A');

  my $card_str = join ' ',
                 map { $display{$_} // $_ }
                 sort { $b <=> $a } @$cards;

  return "$suit{$suit} $card_str";
}
```

Comment: amazing answer, my appreciation for educational approach to address      
the problem and explaining usage of eg. `printf`. I uploaded new version        
with a bit different usage of `printf`, please see my comment to the question.   
The lunch-version of the solution makes my code look like kindergarten-made.    
It may take me some time to understand: `push @{ $hand{$p}{$card->[0]} }...`            
constructs, hopefully not much. Dave, can I copy your version to my repo        
or at least mention it?

Comment: @mtth: Please feel free to use my code in any way you like. I learnt about complex data structures like these by reading [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) - you might find it useful too.

Comment: thanks for pointing to perldsc - I studied the doc a bit for multilevel  
data structures. I updated the repo with the script [link](https://github.com/matthiam1/SPADES/blob/master/q1.pl) 
and also updated printf's format so every hand has column of minimal fixed width 
capable of holding the longest suit possible (13 cards). There was also a minor 
flaw on *undefined value as an ARRAY reference* in case a suit was void. Please 
check if my fix is correct.

Comment: @mtth: Your fix looks fine to me.